# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory while running ionic run android --prod

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, angular2-routing

Getting the following error on **ionic run android --prod** in Ionic2 .cant figure out the why this issue is occuring.

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 
<--- Last few GCs --->

  153833 ms: Mark-sweep 1324.2 (1434.9) -> 1324.1 (1434.9) MB, 713.3 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  154555 ms: Mark-sweep 1324.1 (1434.9) -> 1324.1 (1434.9) MB, 721.0 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  155283 ms: Mark-sweep 1324.1 (1434.9) -> 1326.3 (1413.9) MB, 728.0 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
  156007 ms: Mark-sweep 1326.3 (1413.9) -> 1328.8 (1413.9) MB, 724.2 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x30ce6f3cfb51 <JS Object>
    1: _parseMappings(aka SourceMapConsumer_parseMappings) [/home/neeraj/Desktop/insuranext-mobile/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:463] [pc=0x28d87b18d8cb] (this=0x1f97a1ed4fa9 <a BasicSourceMapConsumer with map 0x7cf5b6bebd1>,aStr=0x275d205bce9 <Very long string[5209]>,aSourceRoot=0x30ce6f304381 <undefined>)
    2: get [/home/neeraj/Desktop/insuranext-mobile/node_modules/sou...

node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x10983ec [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewInternalizedStringImpl(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, unsigned int) [node]
 6: v8::internal::StringTable::LookupString(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [node]
 7: v8::internal::LookupIterator::PropertyOrElement(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool*, v8::internal::LookupIterator::Configuration) [node]
 8: v8::internal::Runtime::GetObjectProperty(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
 9: 0xecfb11 [node]
10: v8::internal::Runtime_KeyedGetProperty(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
11: 0x28d86ca092a7
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What is at line 463 of /home/neeraj/Desktop/insuranext-mobile/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js??

Comment: @JasonSpradlin  segment = cachedSegments[str];

Comment: It would help to see this in context.  Can add the contents of the file to your question?

Comment: mapping = new Mapping();
        mapping.generatedLine = generatedLine;
        for (end = index; end < length; end++) {
          if (this._charIsMappingSeparator(aStr, end)) {
            break;
          }
        }
        str = aStr.slice(index, end);
        segment = cachedSegments[str];
        if (segment) {
          index += str.length;
        } else {
          segment = [];
          while (index < end) {
            base64VLQ.decode(aStr, index, temp);
            value = temp.value;
            index = temp.rest;
            segment.push(value);
          }

Comment: this is the small code snippet from line 442-473 in that file

Comment: Please edit your question and put the snippet in your question.  I tried reviewing the code from the comment, and the brackets didn't match up.  The error ( `JavaScript heap out of memory` ) basically points to an infinite loop in your code, so either the `for` or `while` loop is running forever until javascript runs out of memory.

Comment: @JasonSpradlin ,this is the full file  https://insuranext.s3.amazonaws.com/source-map-consumer.js

Comment: @JasonSpradlin any suggestions?